# Issues with Bootstrap menu overlapping dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with my two navigation menus. I’m using two of the same type navigation that comes with Bootstrap. The first navigation is using the “navbar-inverse” class and the second navigation menu is using “navbar-default” class with some minor modification. The issue appears when you click on dropdown menu in the right corner; the second navigation menu will overlap the dropdown box and only content below the menu is visible.

Please look at the attachment below for illustration.

**This is my current HTML setup:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
        ...
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Innstillinger <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            ...
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**This is my current issue illustrated:**

[image]

I have created a JSfiddle with corresponding stylesheets and frameworks to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/1L3voL3h/. Unfortunately, at this point I haven't been able to find a solution by myself. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">`
to `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">` from your second nav bar

Comment: pleasure helping you :)

Answer (score 2):

just add this for your second navbar

```css
<style>
.second-navbar {
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `z-index` of your navbar-default or of your dropdown menu. Something like:

```
.navbar-default {
    background: #b6d24b;
    border-radius: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

or:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chimos/j2pqt9fe/1/)

You only need to add to your CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top {
    z-index: 800;
}
.navbar-default.navbar-static-top {
    z-index: 700;
}
```

The problem is that you are applying z-index:1000 to both of your navigation bars. With this rule:

```
.navbar-static-top {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

You should change this rule and/or add the ones I provided above to give your first navigation bar a higher z-index value.